# Conditional check in pandas dataframe loc

Tags: python, pandas, syntax

I'm referring to this document https://datatofish.com/if-condition-in-pandas-dataframe/

The part - `(3) IF condition - strings`

I'm trying to implement it with 2 conditions as:

```
x.loc[x.Test Status == 'Finished' and x.Results Validation == 'In Limits', 'Outcome'] = 'PASS'
```

I've a invalid syntax error. How do I handle this? I've tried multiple workarounds like `np.where` but no luck.

Comment: Go down to section 5. The syntax is `(x['Test Status'] == 'Finished') & (x['Results Validation'] == 'In Limits')`. Notice you cannot use `.` to access columns when the column name has a space in it.

Comment: `x.loc[(x.Test Status == 'Finished' )&(x.Results Validation == 'In Limits'), 'Outcome']`

Comment: @Wen-Ben: I tried that. It doesn't work.

Comment: x.loc[(x['Test Status'] == 'Finished' )&(x['Results Validation'] == 'In Limits'), 'Outcome']